# How can I output debug info from hook_node_presave()?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, hooks

I'm learning about module design for Drupal 7 and I want to see what hook_node_presave is being passed (and working with), how can I output debug info so that I can learn how to manipulate it?

Is there a similar hook that I can use to print out debug info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and dump your variables with [dpm](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/8)($input, $name = NULL) to the screen.

[This article](https://ratatosk.backpackit.com/pub/1836982-debugging-drupal) shows additional debugging options.

Comment: "A suite of modules containing fun for module developers and themers ..." - How can I resist? Thanks!

Comment: Works great, thanks for the reference link, some of the pretty print functions are nice.

Comment: you are very welcome

Comment: The link is broken :(